# If the cube of $n$ is divisible by $3$, then $n$ is divisible by $3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Trying to figure the statement $3|n$ iff $3|n^3$. While proving the forward direction was easy and stuck on the reverse direction. Any ideas?

Comment: Take cases for $n=0\pmod 3$, $n=1\pmod 3$ and $n=2\pmod 3$.

Comment: Hint: $3$ is prime.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. If $n^3$ has $3$ in its prime-decomposition, then $n$ must also have, since the prime-decomposition of $n^3$ consists of the composition of $n$ but every prime power is multiplied by $3$.

Answer (score 5):

By [Euclid's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) we have $3$ divides $n^3=n\times n^2$ so $3$ divides $n$ or divides $n^2$ and in this last case we apply this lemma again and we have the desired result.

Comment: Thanks so much! Unfamiliar with fundamental theorem of arithmetic in proof context so your method is perfect.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$n^3-n=n(n^2-1)=(n+1)n(n-1)=6\binom {n+1}3$$ is divisible by $3$ either because it is the product of three consecutive integers, or by the fact that the binomial coefficient is an integer.

I put this up not because it gets to the essence of this problem - which would be true for any prime - but to illustrate a different method which is occasionally helpful.